# HTML: controlling input focus for a radio button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

What exactly determines how the input is focused on a `<label>`? In principle, wrapping a radio `<input>` in a `<label>` ensures that you can click anywhere on the label text to select the radio button:

```
<label>
<input name="foo" type="radio">Fubar
</label>
```

However, this doesn't work if the label text is more complex. The code below is FireBug output for two radio buttons, where one of them has a Bootstrap popover when hovering over the text.

The second button (Bar) is manually-entered HTML, which works as expected (clicking on 'Bar' selects the radio).

The first button (Foo) has no label text in the original HTML, and everything in the `<a ...>Foo</a>` is inserted by JavaScript, to give a popover with a title and some text. The problem is that this radio button can only be selected by clicking on the button itself, and not by clicking on the text. The class `override-link` just turns off link styling (default colour and pointer, no decoration).

Any idea how to expand the focus area for the first button to the entire 'Foo' text?

```
<div class="radio">
  <label id="FooLabel">
    <input id="pg29Radio0" name="pg29Radio" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio">
    <a class="override-link" title="" rel="popover" data-toggle="popover"
         data-content="<div style='font-weight:normal'>
         Foo popover body text</div>"
         href="#" data-original-title="<div style='font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap'>
         Foo popover title text</div>">
       Foo
    </a>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label id="BarLabel">
    <input id="pg29Radio1" name="pg29Radio" value="1" type="radio">
    Bar
  </label>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7d3fvoz/) showing the problem. This shows two radio buttons, with a Bootstrap popover when hovering over the 'Foo' text. You can select the 'Bar' radio by clicking on the 'Bar' text, but you can't do this for 'Foo'.

Comment: Does ```<label for="pg29Radio0">``` work?

Comment: @Drmjo - afraid not

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `<label>` element should actually wrap only the text (and not the input) and you should use the `for="id"` in the label (to let the browser know that this label is the the element with the `id="id"`.
2. The problem that you have is that the `<a>` element "takes over" the click from the `label` element. You can use the `pointer-events` css property on the `label a` to prevent that `a` to take over it:

```css
label a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <input id="pg29Radio0" name="pg29Radio" value="0" checked="checked" type="radio" />
  <label for="pg29Radio0" id="FooLabel">
    <a class="override-link" title="" rel="popover" data-toggle="popover"
       data-content="<div style='font-weight:normal'>
                     Foo popover body text</div>"
       href="#" data-original-title="<div style='font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap'>
                                     Foo popover title text</div>" onclick="this.parent.click();">
      Foo
    </a>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <input id="pg29Radio1" name="pg29Radio" value="1" type="radio" />
  <label for="pg29Radio1" id="BarLabel">
    Bar
  </label>
</div>
```

> Note that if you expect the click on the `a` to open some modal/run some javascript code - this will prevent it.

### update

Since you already use javascript you can use this:

```
 onclick="this.parentElement.click()"
```

On the anchor.

Here is a jsfiddle, based on the one in your comment:
https://jsfiddle.net/2pumb4yy/2/

Comment: Afraid this doesn't work - you don't get a radio button unless the `<label>` is *outside* the `<input>`. The `pointer-events` also causes problems. jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/2pumb4yy/.

Comment: The radio button exists, but you have `margin-left: -20px;` in your css, so it's outside of your view.

Comment: And regarding the `pointer-events` - you can see in my answer that you will have a problem using both `pointer-events` and `javascript`.

Comment: Sorry, been on day job all week. The `onclick` does it.